# ggplot2, applying two scales to the same plot? Top down barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

See plot here:

[image]
(from [here](http://s1.ibtimes.com/sites/www.ibtimes.com/files/styles/v2_article_large/public/2014/03/11/plane-crashes-01.png))

How do I reproduce both the upper and lower portion of the barplot using ggplot2?

For example, I can produce the upper portion with

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(1000, 5)), aes(x=x)) + geom_bar() + scale_y_reverse()
```

However now if I add any other `geom_`, such as another `geom_bar()` the scale for y is reversed. Is it possible to apply the `scale_y_reverse()` to only a specific `geom_`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ggplot only like to have one y-axis scale. The easiest thing would be to basically reshape your data yourself. Here we can use `geom_rect` to draw the data where ever we like and we can condition it on group time. Here's an example

```
#sample data
dd<-data.frame(
  year=rep(2000:2014, 2), 
  group=rep(letters[1:2], each=15), 
  count=rpois(30, 20)
)
```

And now we can plot it. But first, let's define the offset to the top bars by finding the maxima height at a year and adding a bit of space

```
height <- ceiling(max(tapply(dd$count, dd$year, sum))*1.10)
```

And here's how we plot

```
ggplot(dd) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=year-.4, xmax=year+.4, 
    ymin=ifelse(group=="a", 0, height-count), 
    ymax=ifelse(group=="a", count, height), fill=group)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))
```

And that will give us

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to make two separate plots and combine them with `arrangeGrob` from the **gridExtra** package. After playing with the plot margins, you can arrive at something that looks decent.

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(100)
p2 <- ggplot(data.frame(x=rnorm(1000, 5)), aes(x=x)) + geom_bar() + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,0,0,0), 'lines'))
p1 <- p2 + scale_y_reverse() + 
    theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0, 0, -.8, 0), 'lines'), axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
          axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())

p <- arrangeGrob(p1, p2)
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: phantom downvoter! state your name and explain yourself!